Easy way to understand the difference between a cluster variable and a random variable in mixed models
Suppose we have a dataset where we're modeling math achievement scores from socioeconomic status, for a bunch of different schools. The appropriate model using lme4 would be:
lmer(math~ses + (ses | school), data=d)
My students frequently mix up the placement of ses and school. To combat that, I made a YouTube video that helps students identify their "cluster variable." This video gives them three rules to help identify their cluster variable:

Is this variable frequently repeated in your dataset? (cluster variables will repeat)
Does this variable identify a person? (if yes, that's your cluster variable and skip #3)
Does this variable indicate a specific group? (if yes, that's your cluster variable)

For this example, school is going to be repeated (one row for each student in that school), it does not identify a specific person, but it does identify a specific group.
I've never been terribly satisfied with my explanation because it leaves some ambiguity. Let's modify the example to make my rules fail. Suppose we're predicting math scores, but this time, we want to add ethnicity as a predictor. An appropriate model could be:
lmer(math~ses + ethnicity + (ses + ethnicity | school), data=d)
(Assuming slopes actually vary for both ses and ethnicity by school).
The problem with this example is students would be confused, especially if the dataset is not already sorted by school. Both ethnicity and school meet the criteria: both are repeated, neither identify a person, and both indicate a "group." When they ask why ethnicity is not, I'm at a bit of a loss for how to explain why ethnicity is not a group.
Any ideas on how to make the difference more concrete?

This seems like a very interesting question (+1), but maybe I am a bit thick as I cannot really disentangle its difference from the fixed vs. random effects discussion (CV.SE has a great thread on the matter here). What is a different to a "cluster variable" (according to your definition) to a fixed effect?

Great question. You might also add the random-effects tag to it for more visibility.

A very confusing topic, and not just for students and not just in R (SAS codes these completely differently, and differently in different PROCs, this always causes confusion).
Going completely intuitively here (which a) I am more capable of and b) Probably helps more), I would say that there are at least two things to consider:

If we did this study again, would we choose the same levels of the variable?
Are we interested in actually estimating the effect of the variable, or do we just want to avoid problems with the assumption of independence?

In your particular example, if we did it again we would, very likely, get the same ethnicities - White, Black, etc., or however we operationalize the variable in our context, but we would probably not get the same schools.
Also, it seems like you are not interested in the effects of these particular schools (you don't have them as a fixed effect) but you are interested in the effect of ethnicity.
In addition, students should know that what is a cluster variable (to use your term) in one study might not be such in another study. Maybe you are interested in the effect of particular schools!

One slight variation on this, that I like to use to explain it, is if someone else from somewhere else in the world did the study, could they use the same SES levels? (yes) Could they use the same schools? (probably not).

SES levels? Maybe, maybe not. Depends on the place and how SES is measured.  Gabon is not Norway.

Yes that's true. SES isn't the best example to illustrate this point, maybe.

Great question! And Peter's answer is also good. I relay it to my students this way: the “cluster” corresponds to a grouping of observations that represent a second level of sampling and we want to know about variability (eg., in math achievement) across units in that level of sampling as well as the level below. Just as with students, we’re taking the position that schools are a random sample from a population of schools. The goal is not to make specific inferences about school 2's mean being better than school 1's mean or we'd make school a fixed effect and code a contrast for that. Rather, we are curious about the distribution of our fixed effects (eg., intercepts, regression coefficients) across schools, and/or we want to model the dependence among students’ achievement levels within the same school. For example, we might want to estimate the variation in mean math achievement across schools without losing information about the students within the schools, i.e., without aggregating up to the school-level.
This choice of the cluster-unit of sampling is an important design choice that learners should think hard about. Often it is incomplete: in this example, high-school students are also clustered within teachers, who are clustered in schools, but often we ignore that degree of detail (and sometimes not). It’s all about what questions we want to answer and how complicated we want our model to be. Whatever this grouping / clustering variable is, we put it to the right of the | in R's random effects language.
What we put to the left of | indicates what fixed effects we allow to vary across the clusters. In your first example we not only want to know how ses relates to math achievement within each school, but also, how that effect varies across schools. If we simply wanted to allow each school to have its own mean-level of math achievement we’d put a 1 there. To allow the intercepts to vary.
In your second example, we have a characteristic of a student (ethnicity) which is a grouping variable of sorts but we’re not treating the ethnicities as a random sample from a population of possible ethnicities, they are fixed: we only draw inferences about the specific ethnicities in the study. Then, we can also allow those differences between ethnicities to vary across schools, by specifying the model as you have.
For what it's worth, I think it's easier to first get them aquatinted with the hierarchical equations representing the model, so they can see exactly what's going on. Then show them how the combined equation, which is simplified as R code, takes shape based on the hierarchical model. Also, this and related threads may or may not help you help them, but it's worth a look.
